# Unable to read array from req.body in Nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to read array from a request of type application/json using Postman. In Nodejs I am reading the values req.body. All other values are coming fine except array. Array i am getting only first value.

Here is my data

```
{   "title": "test",
    "date": "March 12 12 pm",
    "prize": "100",
    "status": "Ongoing",
    "users": ["1","2"]  
}
```

In Nodejs I am reading like this

```
const { title, data, prize, status, users } = req.body
```

Output is for users I am getting only 1 but not complete array. What went wrong?

This is my app.js:

```
 app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  }),
);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//To allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors());
```

Also I am using express-validator for body

```
        const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
    const { sanitizeBody } = require('express-validator');
    exports.tournamentUpdate = [
      auth,
      body('title', 'Title must not be empty.')
        .isLength({ min: 1 })
        .trim(),
      body('date', 'Date must not be empty.')
        .isLength({ min: 1 })
        .trim(),

      sanitizeBody('*').escape(),
      (req, res) => {
        try {
          const errors = validationResult(req);
          const {
            title,
            prize,
            status,
            users
          } = req.body;



output  req.body.title =  test;
            req.body.prize = 100;
            req.body.users = 1;
```

Here users I am getting value as 1, I want whole array [1,2].

Comment: can you make sure on what is coming on req.body, your destructuring assignment is correct.

Comment: i have edited req.body contains all the properties that i send from postman. Only users i am getting value as 1 instead of array

Comment: I was not able to reproduce using this code: https://pastebin.com/FiS6bRxG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sanitizing arrays have an open [bug](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/791)  for express-validator which you had experienced.

By the time it is fixed, you can exclude the array field from sanitization.

```
  sanitizeBody("title", "date", "price", "status").escape(),
```